# Make hot questions list in stackexchange.com responsive

Tags: feature-request, status-review, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, responsive-design

I have https://stackexchange.com/questions bookmarked on my phone but unlike the rest of SE it isn’t responsive. Conscious choice or just overlooked?

Comment: Bit of both, probably. Most of our work is going into Q&A and Talent these days, and I'm not aware of any plans to update/redesign stackexchange.com... but we can hope.

Comment: Since this feature request is still valid, I'll forward it to the relevant developer team.