# Now live: A fully responsive profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, announcements, responsive-design

### Update

As of 2021-10-21T18:05:38+00:00 this is now live across the network. If you find any issues, you can post them as answers on this question. Try to give some details about your browser and platform if that’s relevant. Thanks for all the feedback so far!

### Original Post

We’ve been chipping away at the user profiles since [the last round of changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368661/additional-profile-refinements). I’m back to share a quick [video tour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se2utD3i4hY) of the final round of changes to the profile on our way to responsiveness. We’d like to deploy these changes later this week, but first wanted to let folks know what we’ve got planned.

Things should now wrap and squish, allowing you to view the entirety of the profile on any device or window size without having to do any horizontal scrolling. Let us know what you think.

We’ll update this post (and title) when the changes are live. They’ll be going live network-wide.

#### Some changes

1. Columns should all line up and have a spacing of 24px. No more weird gaps!
2. Headers across each section are now unified along with their various calls to action
3. Each section now has a card aesthetic
4. Question lists have all moved over to the right column to unify line length and general aesthetic
5. The tags section is now a list
6. We’ve gotten rid of some of the blank slates. For example, if you don’t participate in the network, we don’t need to show the network.

#### Screenshots

If you want to see this in action, check out the [video tour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se2utD3i4hY). Since the feature is live, the screenshots below are linked, rather than embedded, to reduce the amount of necessary vertical scrolling on the page.

#### Desktop

[Desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkqsC.jpg)

#### Tablet

[Tablet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFwMu.png)

#### Phone

[Phone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zynZQ.png)

Comment: Great work, Aaron! Waiting to see this live ASAP. What about the Activity tab and the remaining sections on the Settings tab though? You mentioned in the video that this was the "final round"? Or were you referring to the Profile tab only?

Comment: Both the Settings and Activity sections are being worked on now and will have a similar aesthetic. Settings is way closer. This post is just about the Profile tab, and after this next deploy and round of bug fixes, it will be considered “done”.

Comment: @Ollie should be up on the top right of any user. If they've got meta accounts, or Teams, it's in a dropdown list of "Profiles".

Comment: @AaronShekey It's back now.  It wasn't there, then it was.

Comment: As always... caching?

Comment: Our `messWithOllie` boolean must have been set to `true`  Sorry about that. We've actually been making some changes that _should_ be unrelated there, but I've let some folks know to keep a look out.

Comment: Should questions about this change be posted as separate questions, now this is live?

Comment: If I see something Wierd on the profile page, but I’m not sure whether it’s new or not, should I post it as an answer? Also, should wierd things with the “settings” part of the profile page be posted here?

Comment: Now that the changes are live, I think there's no need to have those long images in the post as they take too much space on the page (and bandwidth too). Maybe they should be converted to links?

Comment: @41686d6564 Agreed. Nice suggestion. Edited!

Comment: @AaronShekey Applaud the use of video finally for UI features. Should be used a lot more! The Help Center would benefit tremendously as would onboarding

Comment: Good job concentrating on UI design and clean-up. Like documentation, the UI (non-critical parts like profiles, etc.) are too often left undone and remain a hodge-podge of input collected across a handful of profile pages. Glad to see the polish being applied to an already great site.

Comment: Since you are already working on "responsifying" stuff: Maybe you can find some time to [add a responsive theme to the HNQ list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299913/138661)? The HNQ list is great for finding a short and interesting Q&A pair to read on your phone while waiting/compiling/etc., and it would be great to have larger fonts for that when viewed on a small screen. All the Q&A themselves are already responsive, it's just [that single page](https://stackexchange.com/) which is missing.

Comment: Fully responsive, but you're still forcing people onto the mobile site when using a mobile device. ***Why?***

Comment: @Larnu Same reason for most things, the code sucks, lol. That mobile site sniffing code has been way too persistent and full of bugs. The good news is it'll be torn out entirely by the end of this year. It's not worth fixing the thing we're gonna delete.

Comment: Is there a reason why I then get forced back onto the Mobile site about once a month then @AaronShekey ? It's really annoying as it can be very abrupt. I can be browsing in the morning, then visit the site again an hour later on the same device and I'm pushed to the mobile site, even though i'd been on the responsive site before. it's *really* frustrating that you're trying to make the whole site responsive, but keep pushing the mobile site on users, even when they've opted to not use it. it feels counter intuitive to the work you're currently doing.

Comment: @Larnu There is a bug in the code that's forgetting your setting. Not worth fixing since it's all getting ripped out in less than a month. Sit tight. I agree, it sucksssssssssssssssss.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by the term "fully responsive"? The meaning of the phrase seems to have drifted over time and I'm really not at all sure what you mean by it.

Comment: @MichaelKay Responsive web design: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design. For us, that means we get all the same functionality regardless of the size of the window or device—without any horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Do we have any plans to add responsive design to various mod tools? Thankfully the flags page is having responsive design. But most other operations for mods are really difficult to handle from a mobile device.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I doubt that that will be coming for a while. They just finished the activity page, and will be getting to the settings page soon. The mod tools are probably a couple more items down the list (if they’re even on the list at all).

Comment: I've been doing it for ages and it's a pain. I do suspect it's eventually on the roadmap cause everything needs to be resoonsivy eventually tho...

Comment: While I don't want to go into details....  I can confirm *some* mod tools have been enhanced and that includes responsive design

Comment: What's the timeline on making the rest of the site responsive as well?

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks I guess 

Comment: Would you still like us to post bug reports due to these changes as answers to this question, or should we be posting them as new questions at this point?

Answer (score 71):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I would like to request that the new profile be made with less space.

Compare the difference:

New:

[image]

Old:

[image]

The new profile is definitely much cleaner, but there's too much space. The older profile was much more compact. Please consider removing some of the spacing. In particular, the whole bar of space on the left side where the top network posts were should be gone. Maybe make a partition after profile, and put everything else after with width:100% of the profile?

Lines have been made shorter. The new grid is smaller than the previous container. I propose to make this margin smaller:

```css
.gs24>.d-flex, .gs24>.flex--item {
    margin: 8px;
}
```

The top tags section has too much padding. Make it half what it is now (12px -> 6px).

Thanks for making the improvements and making the site better.

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/coming-soon-a-fully-responsive-profile/371095#comment1238304_370989) (I think it’s relevant, but I might be misunderstanding).

Comment: I'm not a design guy, so I don't know if this is possible but I think having the top meta posts and top network posts positioned exactly the way they were ( when on desktop view) and having them move to the current position on tablet and mobile views would be ideal (if it can be done).

Comment: What about putting badges to the left, they fit quite nicely there: [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxooL.png)? That way:
1. Badge counts would be on the left, like it was before;
2. On smaller screen sizes they would move to the bottom, like it was before, so it would also solve the issue of people complaining about badges being at the top.

Comment: "The top tags section has too much padding" – much like the posts as well...

Answer (score 47):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### [Please address the Last Seen entry on profiles.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368870/175248)

Either put the debate to rest or revert this change which had nothing originally to do with making the profile responsive in the first place.

Comment: How is this different from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371142/560258)?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica:  Measured and restrained impatience on my part, while explicitly stating two desired outcomes? :D  Probably isn't different, to be honest.

Comment: I'm generally against duplicate answers and retreading old ground, but this isn't one of those cases. I think it's good to repeatedly keep poking this. It can't be a real privacy concern if it's still available to the API and still stored in SE's databases under user ID.

Comment: We’ve restored "last seen" to all users, but with less granularity.

Comment: @AaronShekey:  And the rationale for reducing the granularity to *a month* was...?

Comment: @Makoto i see "this week" for both me and you. *good enough* for what i use it for,

Comment: @KevinB:  [It breaks the small-site use case entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368965/175248). It also defies the sentiment of what I hoped was the outcome; either a *reversion* of the change or *a firm decision on why they went the way they did*.  I'm really not trying to be a jerk about this. I'm hoping that I'm sounding level-headed about this whole thing, but I vehemently hate this pattern of breaking things within the community and then offering an olive branch in the form of something we didn't ask for as a "compromise".  That doesn't feel like a "community" engagement to me.

Comment: I don't disagree with you at all, this pattern has been repeating for years (Overcorrect, then 6-8 arbitrary units later half-revert)... I more wanted to point out that it's per week, not month as you stated. I'd certainly prefer what we had, or at least reasoning for why it needed to change that goes into more detail than "privacy", but also... as i said, it does at least resolve the issue for me, personally, ;)

Comment: @KevinB:  The furthest it goes back is "more than a month".  For my use case, that's as granular as I can get.  Even if they did add one more order of magnitude (maybe two), it still doesn't explain why that decision was made or what it had to do with making the profile responsive in the first place.

Comment: I just found a "last seen more than 2 years ago"

Comment: @KevinB:  I found one too.  That took some digging.  Well...that's still less than useful in my case anyway...

Comment: It would be nice for a post to exist that actually explained the way it is rather than having to figure it out

Comment: Last seen, in its original granularity of _seconds_, is a potential vector for abuse. When discussing with our trust & safety team, we determined that knowing someone used the site within a week is plenty of granularity and should satisfy existing use cases. Now, public users can see if the user has participated this week, more than a week ago, more than a month ago, and more than `x` years ago.

Comment: @AaronShekey out of curiosity, is the “last seen” method calculated the same way still, or is it calculated differently?

Comment: @AaronShekey: Okay, I suppose then if this were explained or communicated to us in a way that didn't bundle it into a feature like this, I could've supported the rationale. In that framework, we could've had a conversation on what granularity makes the most sense with the people that use it for non-abusive reasons. But I get the distinct impression that we're either stuck with this compromise or nothing at all.

Comment: @AaronShekey 1) Do mods still see the original granularity of seconds/is that still exposed via the API? 2) It would be nice if we could at *least* see down to the day. Hell, hide it behind a 10k privilege to massively reduce the surface area for that theoretical risk for abuse. The ability to know a user has been on the site is really useful when trying to engage with *people* at an individual question level. We can sort of approximate this in the positive by checking "recent activity" (if there has been some, we know they've been active), but obviously isn't possible in the negative.

Comment: @Makoto The thing that's tricky from the outside is understanding that the profile has seen little to no investment over the years. No one quite "owns" that part of the site. My team has the mandate to make things responsive. While we're there, we can do things that have often been discussed, but weren't justified because of this lack of ownership/governance. I believe we're leaving the profile a more responsive, safer place.

Comment: @TylerH Mods can see what you see when you view your own profile. We discussed putting things behind rep and potential preferences, but this is the cheapest way to make the profile a bit safer, beyond the _cheapest_ solution, which was to remove it altogether.

Comment: @AaronShekey:  [I'm just getting a wicked sense of deja-vu, that's all.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367899/new-staff-and-mod-labels-on-site-metas-and-meta-stack-exchange/367925#comment1229056_367925)  But I think I've said enough about this.  While I'm not satisfied with this compromise, this is all I'm going to get.

Answer (score 45):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Because I have joined all the communities on Stack Exchange, my profile has a massive scrollbar and loads of whitespace:

[image]

Can this be changed to as it was before and not show hidden communities?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by _"not show hidden communities"_? And how was it before for your profile with all those hidden communities? Looking at the screenshot in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291708/348196), it doesn't seem like much has changed.

Comment: @41686d6564 I certainly didn't have such a massive scrollbar.

Comment: In practice all our CMs would have the same problem

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Apparently, the problem is just with hidden communities (there's no max.) - For example, [Catija's profile lists only 5 communities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxyeE.png) but if you click on "View all", you see all the remaining ones. So, users who don't have (many) hidden communities will not notice the problem.

Comment: Hmm... the logic in this section changed a bit when we moved the edit/view all links to the top instead of below. This could definitely use some tweaking. Let me see what we can do here to make this experience a bit better.

Comment: Updated! Since viewing every item is semi-important to the functionality here, we took a light touch approach and left the list intact, but made it scrollable.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not just CMs. I'm registered to 178 sites and many of the other people fighting network-wide spam are too.

Answer (score 31):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Since our profile page is now updated can we also consider bringing back old feature Last Seen?

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368870/560258)

Comment: We’ve restored "last seen" to all users, but with less granularity.

Comment: @AaronShekey any chance that we could add one extra level of detail? I think it would be usefull to add today (time <=24h) as the finest level now appears to be one week. While from a privacy standpoint that sounds good, it is not really usefull.

Comment: I would match it to the same level of detail as on the stackexchange.com network profile, which already was less granular than what was on site profiles previously.

Answer (score 26):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Can someone explain what a *card aesthetic* is? (Sorry, I'm not a design guy.)

> 3. Each section now has a card aesthetic

Also, when you squish down to `320x` resolution on the *Profile*, the *Stats* are below the *Badges* and *Top Posts* sections. That's surprising because usually I'd expect the *Stats* summary towards the top.

Comment: Card aesthetic refers to the [cards component of Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/cards/) - essentially putting each section into its own box with a border and padding.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to maintain the positioning of stats _and_ maintain 2 columns. You can stack one or the other on top, and I chose to put content on top in the smallest breakpoints. We could change the source order at various breakpoints, but we generally try to avoid doing that for performance reasons. Could be worth revisiting though!

Comment: @AaronShekey Have are you familiar with [`grid-template-areas`](https://tomduffytech.com/responsive-layout/)?    I've been super excited to use them to re-order elements on the page using just CSS.   You have to use a grid rather than columns, but I've managed to make grids that approximate columns when needed.

Answer (score 26):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Make it more clear what “posts %” means.

On the “Top tags” section of a users profile page, there is a section labeled “posts %”. As far as I can tell, this means the percentage of your posts that are tagged with or answer a question tagged with those tags. Could this be renamed “percentage of posts” to make it more clear?

Comment: Agreed, this is really vague as-is. Before the most recent set of changes it read as `Posts % ##`, so at least this is an improvement! You're correct in your assumption that this is `(number of posts with this tag) / (total post counts) * 100`. I'll mark as [tag:feature-request] and see what we can do to make this more obvious without being too wordy.

Comment: @BenKelly maybe a different tooltip text for the `posts %` (the others two fields don't leave ambiguity).

Comment: @BenKelly, not sure if this is improvement, the "score" and "posts %" look much more awkward now. IMO, this looked better before, but missed the ":" to be completely clear. As for the solution, you could just move the % to the beginning (`XX% of posts`) or combine it with posts completely (`XX posts (YY%)`).

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Both `XX% of posts` and `XX% / posts` seem like better implementations than the current one.

Answer (score 22):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Where's reputation?

When you're browsing on mobile maybe you want to see how much rep a commenter has. You try to hover over their name but you realize tool tips are completely inaccessible on a touch screen. You visit their profile but the number is nowhere in sight.

.

.

.

.

Yeah it's all at the bottom (with only communities after it). Many will give up before they reach it. The rest will be annoyed. Please keep it near the top, maybe near account age. It should be above the fold so it can be seen easily, for example in mobile Safari's preview (where you wouldn't need to leave to go to the profile page).

Comment: [Kind of a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370967/818993), I guess. "Kind of" because the other answer looks more a question/comment than a feature request.

Comment: This is due to the way we stack the columns on mobile. I agree though that it could be better executed. We'll review internally and see what we can do here.

Comment: I'd suggest moving the stats card to be between about me and badges.  Putting the text first is reasonable, but overall rep is probably more likely to be of interest than any of the other cards.

Comment: Updated. On mobile views, we move the stats card to the very top, just under the shared "tabs" area.

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

"Unregistered" overlaps the Network Profile button on mobile. The profiles that this happens in keep on changing though.

Currently, I see it in [this unregistered profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/444577/user444577) and [this registered profile with a long name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1132878/matthew-de-la-rosa)

---

These accounts below I discovered and then they stopped showing the behavior.

Here's a [random profile](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/148624/soojin-yi):

[image: Bug image]

Sometimes names do too, as in this [other profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1095131/hlaphyokyaw-1952):

[image: Bug image 2]

Note: discovered after a [related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371112/323179) was apparently fixed.

[Another profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/440216/user440216) that does:

[image: bug 3, unregistered overlaps again]

Comment: Looks like this was fixed.

Comment: @LShaver Actually, it keeps on popping up but in new profiles. I think I last saw it a few hours ago. I'll see if I can find the accounts again

Comment: Also reported here in more detail: [Long usernames overlap with the Profiles/Network profile button on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378753/long-usernames-overlap-with-the-profiles-network-profile-button-on-mobile)

Answer (score 19):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Could the design prioritise Top Meta Posts over Top Network Posts? From my own profile,

[image]

Personally, I'm much more interested in the top meta posts of a user than their top network posts, and so a 3 vs 7 question ratio doesn't show the extent of meta contribution that I'd like to see. Perhaps changing to 7 vs 3, or maybe 5 vs 5, would be better?

Comment: I agree that the 3/7 ratio can certainly be improved now that we've moved these posts from the cramped left sidebar to the main area. I was curious if the numbers are set to these values for a specific reason, so I dove into the git history for them. It looks like they've been this way since ~2014 and there wasn't any specific reason for their values. I'll tweak this to 5/5 (or similar, depending on feedback) for the next round of changes.

Comment: 5/5 is a good ratio

Comment: This is now live as 5/5. I'm still open for suggestions on increasing/decreasing the values, but it looks good to me for now.

Comment: @BenKelly 5/5 is probably the way to go unless you change the behavior depending on if a user is going to the profile page from the main site or from meta.  (This is probably not worth the confusion it would inevitably cause.)

Answer (score 19):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make the “see more” buttons' text more consistent.

Currently, they are:

- "View all badges"
- “View all [number] tags”
- “View all questions and answers”
- “View all” (for top network posts).

Can these be changed to be more consistent? One possible suggestion might be:

- "View all badges"
- “View all tags”
- “View all questions and answers”
- “View all top network posts”

Another alternative with shorter text:

- "All badges"
- “All tags”
- “All site posts”
- “All top network posts”

<sub>Taken from a [helpful comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile/371095?noredirect=1#comment1238622_371095).</sub>

Comment: In some of these cases, we left the text that was already there, but I can see the appeal of fixing it up while we're in here. We could probably go entirely one way (show `View all ## whatever`) or the other (just `View all`). I'll bring this up internally and see what we'd like to do.

Comment: @BenKelly I would like to see the links stay descriptive for accessibility reasons. If you have to see how the page is laid out to understand what the link does, that would be bad.

Comment: Updated. All links have been standardized to `View all XYZ`.

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Code blocks don't wrap or create a scrollbar when the content exceeds the width of the 'About' section, causing the entire section to stretch:

[image]

[Profile page](https://stackapps.com/users/76056/spectric?tab=profile) showcasing the issue.

Comment: Is there anything else that causes this bug (tables comes to mind as a likely candidtate) or is it just code blocks?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica looks like it's only the code blocks. Tested with tables; appears to work.

Comment: This has been reported before: [My profile page just literally broke after adding several code blocks](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412429/4642212), and I’m pretty sure it’s been reported at least once before that as well.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I actually reported it nearly [2 months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369303/8630150), but with the new profile update it still hasn't been fixed, so I decided to post again.

Comment: I wondered about this as well as I also have comment templates [within my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915423/helvete?tab=profile). I find the behaviour actually really irresponsive:-)

Comment: Oh goodness... As another commenter (on a deleted duplicate post) aptly put it - "Widest profile in the west!". We'll look into this and see if we can't get a fix out in the next round of changes.

Answer (score 16):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

**Tl;dr:** The link to view all of a user's badges or tags doesn’t look like a link.

Most of the links on the page look like links. This applies to posts, links in the profiles, and probably some other stuff.

However, the links that say “View all badges” and “View all [number] tags” aren’t formatted to look like links (by this, I mean the text color).

Can these please have their color changed to look more like links?

Comment: The color choice on these links was purposeful. However, that doesn't mean that your suggestion is invalid. I'll mark this as a [tag:feature-request] and follow up internally.

Comment: @BenKelly Also, they should be consistent. Currently they are: Badges: View all badges, Top tags: View all 44 tags, Top network posts: View all

Answer (score 13):

Why not use the tablet design on PC as well? What is the use for that massive amount of whitespace on the left?

Comment: Looking at it in the video, it seems like a very sensible use of space.  I think it's just awkward because of the very tall screenshots.

Comment: Some users will have more stuff in that left column. Putting everything into a single column at that window width will create some really awkwardly-wide content areas. Some sections look better at the smaller column width as well. The goal is readability, not a white space-free website.

Comment: @AaronShekey what else could possibly be there then? Will te communitites list be expanded automatically? Or are there any teams or channel things listed there?

Comment: We've got collectives and hidden communities. Would it feel better if that column were on the right?

Comment: I don't think that matters much @AaronShekey, but perhaps include those in a screenshot so people see the space being used.

Comment: @AaronShekey What about putting badges to the left, they fit quite nicely there: [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxooL.png)? That way:
1. Badge counts would be on the left, like it was before;
2. On smaller screen sizes they would move to the bottom, like it was before, so it would also solve the issue of people complaining about badges being at the top.

Comment: @Luuklag since you don’t consider this [tag:support] or a [tag:feature-request], what would you consider this?

Comment: It was just a question @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica. I'm perfectly aware of the tags we have and what purpose they serve. This question doesn't need any.

Comment: @Luuklag most of the answers to this question have tags.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica And they're typically used so that employees can pair them with status tags as the relevant request/bug report is handled. There's no feature request here, or a bug report - just a question, which can easily be answered, or discussed, in the comments. Tagging doesn't help on answers like these.

Comment: @Spevacus We may discuss as much as we like, but if there are no tags there will be no changes as well, so this discussion becomes quite useless...

Comment: @EvgenKo423 I don't know where you get that idea from, but that is definitely not true. If staff sees merit in a certain proposal they will follow up on that, regardless of tags in a question. If staff sees the need, they can always add a tag themselves.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Letters in profile name overlap with the edit profile button

Currently, my [profile on stack apps](https://stackapps.com/users/80362/ekadh-singh-qwertyuiop-aszdl?tab=profile) looks like:

[image: Name overlapping edit profile button]

To me.

This bug can most likely be reproduced by you if you change your username to “Ekadh Singh - Qwertyuiop ASzdL” (my current name on Stack Apps) or “LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL”, though other names might also work.

Comment: Note: it might also be possible to get it to overlap with the “network profile” button, but I haven’t been able to do that yet.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue (more or less) at in-between breakpoints. _Usually_ the words wrap, but there are some cases where they don't. We'll look into this a little harder and see if we can't get a fix out in the next round of changes. Thanks for the report!

Comment: This should now be improved a bit.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica This bug report shows that it can overlap the "Network profile" button: [User name overlaps Network Profile button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387867).

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

A minor point:

The placeholder text for a person who has some activity (e.g. asked a question), but who has not yet earned any badges, is:

> This user has not earned any rare badges.

[image]

It should be:

> This user has not earned any badges.

The panel will show the rarest badges which have been earned by the user (up to three of them, I think). However these may not be "rare" at all - just the rarest earned so far:

[image]

My screenshots are from [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412480/what-is-a-rare-badge), in case that is relevant.

Comment: I have no idea what you’re talking about. My [stack overflow informed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=13591072) is extremely rare. (This comment isn’t serious, it’s a joke.)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica - You may well think that being informed is a rarity - but [I couldn't possibly comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oz8RjPAD2Jk).

Comment: I don't have a very strong opinion on the specific wording here, so I took a peek back through time to see the (git) history on this. It looks like the wording _used_ to be as you suggest, but was explicitly changed to add "rare" back in mid 2015. I'll mark as "status-review" and ask around to see why this was (the git commit comment isn't terribly helpful on this one).

Comment: As is usually the case with git commits @BenKelly

Comment: @BenKelly It doesn't seem like all badges are shown, but the criteria is unclear: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287093/349058

Comment: @GoodDeeds https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Ah okay, thanks! In that case it might help to provide a definitive answer to the linked question as well.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I'll take a look at the code to see what exactly the criteria is for a "rare" badge and add an answer to that post you linked.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In [this previous FR-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371105) a user had subscribed to all sites on the SE network and the list didn't collapse which made the profile very long vertically.

The above FR was marked `status-completed` but now I'm having the inverse problem. I'm a member of just a few communities but even so:

- The Communities list is very short and only displays 11 communities (it's inconvenient having to scroll when such can be avoided).
- The list height should be adjusted as a function of the elements on the right side, because otherwise there's no gain to having the shortened Communities list other than empty space.
- The scroll bar (possibly a browser setting) is oversized if we zoom out.

Can the height of the Communities list be made to adjust itself to the height of the sections in the right-side column?

[image]

Comment: Unless you have a different username per community and no common reference between them (such as avatar, part of the profile string, or other leaking (meta)data), hiding such things is just a waste of time especially if you leak the user ID. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @PeterBadida do you mean blurring the community names? The point was blurring specifics (TMI) which would be irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [security](/questions/tagged/security)

#### Tl;dr

It is (sometimes) possible to get (some) people to click on malicious links that while trying to click on the “read more” button.

#### More explanation

For example, on [my stack apps profile](https://stackapps.com/users/80362/ekadh-singh-qwertyuiop-aszdl?tab=profile), there is a link hidden behind the “read more” button (for certain browsers), so clicking near (but not directly on) the “read more” button (possibly because of a misclick), can cause you to click on a hyperlink that you didn’t know was there.

Of course this “trick” will only work on people using the browser that you set the trap up for (you can approximate the placement of the hyperlink fairly well by using different sized hearers and html tags iirc), but causing people to accidentally click a malicious hyperlink that they didn’t know was there (even if it only works sometimes, on some browsers) can cause harm.

#### Possible solution

When a hyperlink is mostly or completely hidden, don’t allow it to be clicked on. (This solution might have other problems, it’s just something I thought of from the top of my head).

Comment: Note: the link is no longer there in my stack apps profile.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

If you have one badge of a certain color, it’s at the bottom, instead of the top where it used to be.

Currently, on my [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/560258/ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica?tab=profile), where I have one gold badge, it is at the bottom of the gold badges box, whereas previously it was at the top.

Can it be moved back to the top of the box?

| Current state | Expected state |
| --- | --- |
| [image: List of golden badges with a single badge, aligned to the bottom. There is a space for three badges.] | [image: The same list, but the badge is aligned to the top.] |

Note: this was originally a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report and tagged [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) ([see the revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/371104/2)), so I’m changing it to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was decided that it's bydesign (did Aaron elaborate on the retag?) - For reference, the way the badges used to be stacked can be seen in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366832/348196).

Comment: @41686d6564 the reason for the retap was that this answer was originally tagged bug, and it was intentional.

Comment: The border should actually shrink to fit the content instead.

Comment: Personally, I don’t think that would look good (of course, I’m not a design person). Feel free to submit your own answer as a feature request if you want that to happen.

Comment: @Aaron Hi Aaron, could you provide an explanation for why this was declined? To me it seems to make sense because we usually read (in English anyways), left-to-right and top-to-bottom. So it makes sense for tags to be aligned to the top. But perhaps there is some design consideration from your perspective that you can share.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [sponsored-tags](/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Sponsored tag icon's alignment is not properly aligned in the **Top tags** section.

**Sponsored tag with alignment issue:**

[image: Sponsored tag with icon alignment issue]

[image: Sponsored tag with icon alignment issue]
Same sponsored tag icon in the **Tags** page:

[image: Sponsored tags with proper alignment]

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue locally. We'll get this fixed in the next round of changes. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

#### "Last seen more than 1 years ago"

If a user has not logged in for more than one year, but less than two years, the "last seen" field has an errant plural:

[image]

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371530/pluralization-bug-in-last-seen-field)

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Viewing [newest/top] [posts/questions/answers] no longer shows how many questions and answers a user has. This can be viewed on [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/560258/ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica?tab=profile), as well as anybody else’s.

Can this be changed so that it shows how many questions and/or answers a user has posted there?

Why I want this: the amount of questions and answers a user has posted can help tell wether or not the user primarily answers, primarily asks questions, and how active the user is on the site.

Comment: This can be seen in Stats section, but yeah, the number was here before.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 but, but, then I have to *click*. And I’m *far* to lazy to do that.

Comment: Click what? The stats is shown in the top left corner of a profile, where the profile picture used to be. You'll _do have to click_ if it will be shown in the posts section header...

Comment: @EvgenKo423 I thought you were referring to something else, my bad.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On mobile, when a tag is too long the score, post count and post percentage move to a new line, which in itself is fine. But could we please keep a right alignement on the new line?

[image]

Comment: The three "columns" should also be aligned.

Comment: It looks more aligned and accurate when it's on the left.

Comment: I agree that aligning to the right would look better here, as that would keep the three columns aligned with the rows that _aren't_ wrapping. In the process of testing this, I may have accidentally ran across another bug entirely, so thanks for the report!

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Since *last seen* has been brought back (big thanks for that), can we also receive the number of profile views back?

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The badge multiplier looks weird on a narrow screen. From the [same profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321579/scorb) as in [another of my report's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371538/339911) here.

> [image: Badge multiplier]

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Bring back the timestamp links to recent activity under "Bookmarks"

I clicked to my "bookmarks" page today,<sup>1</sup> and I was somewhat annoyed to find that I can no longer click to the last activity for the bookmarked post. The timestamp appears to be when the question was asked, and it is not a link.

[image: bookmarks page screenshot]

Please compare to the new homepage rollout where the **modified X mins ago** text links directly to that recent activity. This is kind of *why* I bookmark posts. I don't want the spam from "Following" lots of them. But every once in a while, I cruise through the yellow-background ones to see if something catches my fancy. Often this results in downvoting new duplicate answers, but sometimes I find a gem to polish or to upvote.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I do this every few weeks, but today I finally decided to gripe about it. (Sorry the regression report comes so late.)</sub>

Comment: FYI, this is very similar, basically a duplicate, of my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372635/562482) to the later [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/562482) question. I found it annoying then, and still find it annoying now, so I hope this change or fix this soon.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry about that. Yours does have precedence. Upvoted.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When I select "Enable Responsiveness" in "Full Site" on my Android phone, there are different layouts on the Network Profile pages for different users. For example, CM Rosie's renders OK with their details under their avatar:

[image: ²]
<sub>Original photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZg8.jpg</sub>

Whereas CM Vanny's is side-aligned causing overlap with the page's title:

[image]
<sub>Original photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgOSe.jpg</sub>

As I'm using Full Site view, I'm not sure whether or not this has something to do with [deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) - apologies if it does.

Comment: The overlapping issue has already been reported: [Letters in profile name overlap with the edit profile button](/a/371112/289905), ["Unregistered" overlaps Network Profile button](/a/371319/289905). The only difference is that the layout can _change_ based on various circumstances. In this case, Rosie’s profile’s breakpoint for shifting the name into the next line is at a width of 816px (can’t tell why this is), whereas the breakpoint for Vanny’s profile is at a width of 316px (which is when the “Moderator” label hits the right edge).

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When a user finishes editing their profile, take them back to the profile main page.

Currently, when you edit your profile, and click save changes (FYI you don’t need to actually change anything for this to work, so feel free to test it), it says that your profile has been saved successfully. After this however, if you want to go back to the profile main page to see what it now looks like, you have to either click cancel (which, after just editing your profile, would make no sense to do), or scroll back up and change to your profile page.

Could there be an automatic redirect to your profile page after editing it?

If that’s not an option, would it be possible to disable or remove or do something with the “cancel” button, because being able to click cancel after making an edit, and have the edit stay doesn’t really make sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The scrollbar for running through your Hidden Communities list is way too close to the link to the hidden community opposite:

[image]

That's annoying, as I keep click-dragging my reputation counter into another window (it also just doesn't look great).  A margin of `10px` there would look better and avoid misclicking:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization)

"posts" word ("сообщения" in Russian) should use plural forms to respect posts count.

> [image: Top tags]

In the picture above the correct form will be:

> 516 сообщени**й**
> 42 сообщени**я**
> 75 сообщени**й**
> 37 сообщени**й**
> 21 сообщени**е**
> 25 сообщени**й**

For the sake of justice this issue is not related to Aaron's work (making the design responsive), but it would be nice to fix the localization issue for this page. However I'm not sure if that fix is under Aaron's code competence.

Comment: huh, are you saying there are multiple ways to write the same word? I think you would also need to define the logic here then, when to use one word over the other, as I don't see any logic behind your wording. It's not odd and even values or is it?

Comment: @Luuklag please look at this [link](https://www.russianlessons.net/lessons/lesson11_main.php) with explanation of plurals in Russian. Just first link I found via Google.

Comment: If you wan't to make a case for something, it is common courtesy that you explain why something is necessary. You can't expect anyone to go look up how plurals work in russian.

Comment: Slavic numbers are a common (thorny) corner case for anything related to localization.

Comment: @Luuklag explain what? I’m not a linguist to make a good explanation. Plurals (for Russian language as well) are supported in SE internationalization part of engine, so SE devs just need to wrap these words into something like tr() function call to fix the issue. After that I can make a correct translation via ru.traducir.win.

Comment: In english it's always in plural: "[1 posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6Me.png)". I think it's easier to understand the problem now.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Please bring back the posts (and tags) count

The "Top Tags" and "Top/Newest Posts" sections used to display the count like this:

[image]

But that's no longer displayed on the responsive profile:

[image]

**Can you please bring it back?**

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371102

Comment: Hmm. I’d say the number of tags is a rather useless metric; the number of posts is more-or-less redundant, as the number of questions and answers is prominently shown above in the Stats box.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek _"the number of tags is a rather useless"_ I actually only care about the number of posts but I included tags for consistency and because other users might find it useful. _"the number of posts is more-or-less redundant"_ I disagree. When one's looking at posts, the stats box is not visible. You'd have to a) know that it's there, and b) scroll up to find it.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The "Top tags" section takes about twice the height now while having lots of white space in the middle. Please make it more like an old style for desktop view:

[image]

1. Show 5 tags instead of 6;
2. Make the first one full-line and the other ones half-line;
3. Make tag names (and maybe numbers as well) on each level different in size.

On smaller screen sizes they will just wrap and stretch to a full line.

Comment: It takes up more space, yes, but I think presenting it as a consistent list is much more readable. 

Comment: @AaronShekey The purpose of the old design was to visually show a "weight" of each tag (like a tag clouds seen on some sites), which IMO was more readable even if you wouldn't read the stats at all. Ideally the sizes should correspond to the score % rather than having fixed sizes.

Comment: I've got a `TODO` to explore adding that back. We can still provide weighted tags in a list.

Comment: @AaronShekey what was the decision on weighted tags?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is a change resulting from the changes to responsive, but the buttons are nearly unreadable with the light gray text, this is on Stack Overflow profiles.

This is with the Chrome Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: orange with light gray text buttons]
[image: orange with light gray text button light mode]

Comment: Your screenshot looks way worse then it does when I directly view my own profile. Although I hardly think this has anything to do with this announcement. You are better off posting this as a separate question.

Comment: Is this a bug report or a support question?

Comment: I'm on the same browser, and the same OS, and I can't figure out how you're seeing this. [This is what I see](https://imgur.com/a/Gd4cNXd). It's at least readable, even though I agree that the contrast is pretty horrible and it fails all WCAG contrast standards. (Looks like it's white-on-orange, not grey-on-orange...?)

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The badges that showed on hover over the communities list are gone. Can we have them back?

[image: screenshot of communities list in user profile]

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

For the semi-narrow page we see that badges blocks are split in 2 rows. Top row contains "gold" and "silver" badges blocks and the bottom row contains "bronze" block:

> [image: Badges]

Since the gold badges have more weight on SE sites I suggest to split badges blocks in different manner, i.e. leave "gold" on the first row, and other blocks on the second. E.g.:

> [image: Suggested badges]

Comment: This is just flex-box doing what flex-box does. I'll see if I can make gold span the row you want, but it's really dependent on content that's very specific to the user.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the communities list some sites have the descenders cut off. This may be an issue specific  to how Firefox [handles fonts with lower baselines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372673#comment1244747_372673) because it only happens with some list items that have descenders but not with all of them.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Checking my profile right now, I don't see how to list all the communities I'm a member of, as you can see in the image:

[image]

I can actually see them if I press Edit, but that would be to hide communities... Previously (I don't quite recall when) we were able to expand this list and see all communities. Was that intentionally removed?

Comment: This was changed recently due to [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371105) and afterwards another change to the fixed size of the [hidden communities list was requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371247). I haven't tested it with visible communities.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Currently the "top overall" part of the Stats block could occupy three lines:

1. icon
2. top N%
3. overall

> [image: Top overall]

It was found on [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321579/scorb) for the page width in range [964..1190] pixels.

Looking at the GIF image above, you can see that all of these elements could fit into the single line. Could this please be fixed?

Ideally I'm expecting the following in result:

> [image: Expected result]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's already one line, and on small screen that's what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axe1B.png so assuming you mean you want to split it to three lines (?) I'm against this request.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 don't believe my gif? Please check out [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321579/scorb)

Comment: Your local browser might be affected by userscripts, or just different kind of browser that act in different way than my own, I can only be sure of what I see for myself.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I don't use userscripts. I can confirm same behavior (as in gif) for Chrome, Firefox even in private mode.

Comment: I can confirm that the linked profile behaves as shown in the gif for me (Firefox 94, Linux, no userscripts). What exactly happens most likely depends on available fonts etc. But clearly, the underlying issue is that the “top 22% overall” thingy is restricted to the left column instead of the full width of the Stats box; I have no idea if it’s feasible to change that.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Under my logins, there are logins named the type of login that they are.

For example, on my profile, it looks like

[image: my logins page]

And on another user's profile page it looks [similar](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9043175#9043175).

Is this intentional, and if it is, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: The changes made here only apply to the User Profile _view_ page found at e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current. I'd recommend asking this as a separate question so we don't accidentally lose track of it here.

Answer (score 2):

I still get horizontal scrolling, albeit less than [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369356):

[image: User profile with right-side content hidden due to horizontal scrolling]

I'm using Firefox 91.0.2 on Ubuntu 18 (91.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).

Comment: That's the activity page, as indicated by the "Activity" tab being active. That's not what was made responsive. The responsive changes were made to the "Profile" page which is what other users see when they click your username.

Comment: Is it possible you’re zoomed in?

Comment: See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile#comment1238302_370964).

Comment: @41686d6564 being worked on ≠ finished worked on, live

Comment: @VScode_fanboy I never said it was finished; quite the opposite actually. The author of this answer is reporting a "bug" about a horizontal scrollbar on the Activity tab. So, I'm referring them to a comment by an SE employee confirming that the Activity tab is _not_ yet responsive as others have also pointed out in the comments here.

Comment: @41686d6564 try to give the opinion-fact together with the link next time. :)

Comment: @CaveJohnson it seems that for manveti (as well for me) "profile" means entire group of pages (profile + activity + settins). So when I first saw the announcement says "A fully responsive profile" I expected to see all of these pages tuned for responsive design. Maybe the OP could choose another more obvious title for the post.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Profile image proportions are broken for some user profiles in a narrow view. [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard-is-vaccinated-v3):

> [image: Narrow Wizard]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Switching profiles (main/meta) via dropdown on the top right corner always change the tab to "activity". It's very annoying since activity tab is not adapted for responsiveness yet.

> [image: profile switch]

Comment: It only goes to "Activity" if it's your own profile; for other users, it goes to the "Profile" tab. (It always worked like this.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek interesting is there a reason for such behavior.

Comment: I suppose the rationale is that you already know who you are, hence you are not particularly interested in the general information about yourself shown on the Profile tab; showing Activity is more helpful.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek but why change the current tab at all? I prefer to see same tab during switching profiles.

Comment: For mods, clicking a link to a profile _always_ goes to Activity. This is super tricky and a really weird user experience, in my opinion. I'm not sure what to do about it, or what we can even afford to do. Here's a spicy take for a perfect hypothetical world: Why do we even have a profile _and_ activity? They overlap a lot. I think those pages can be merged.

Comment: @AaronShekey I absolutely want the detail if I'm checking my profile -or someone's recent contributions in detail- but for most cases that's TMI and checking a user's profile tab gives a quicker digest (and that's most checks we'll tend to do). An argument can also be made that a lot of users are beginners and having 2 separate tabs avoids overloading them making for a beginner-friendly UX. Although, from a purely dev POV maintaining a single merged tab probably would make more sense...

Answer (score 2):

We seem to have lost timestamps on reputation changes prior to the current date. Was this intentional? It can be helpful for spotting serial voting at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Perhaps there is an inconsistency in alignments **if we compare the Profile page with the Activity page**.

The same *"View all"* links have different alignments with the section headers between pages. In the Profile page they are center aligned with the section title while in the Activity page they have an offset and aren't center aligned nor on the same line.

###### Profile page

[image]

###### Activity page

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On the Profile page in the "Top network posts" section the site icons are offset relative to the score and the post text that are centered with each other. I think it would make more sense to center the site icons with the score.

[image: screenshot of top network posts section]

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There is so much empty space in the profile view on the top. Can it be improved?

[image: Profile's page top, with some empty space above About section]

Maybe decrease profile pic and put Member For, Visited, GitHub Id and Location in one line

Comment: @RafaelTavares in that the user is only talking about the bottom space but here I am refering to both the bottom space and top space.

Comment: When you see it on Activity's tab, it doesn't seem too much empty space. I think you have this impression because of the space on the right side of the About title. I personally think this amount of space is ok.

Comment: While I agree with this, it's not particularly specific in terms of a fix, and because this problem is inherent in the redesign that caused it, it would require a lot of work in reverting/redesigning things, so an effective report on it should at least include a proposed fix via mockup or wireframe, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please include the text

> View all [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns) and [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waffles)

When a user has between one and ten (maybe a slightly different number, I’m not sure) of posts

Context: when a user has between one to ten(?) posts, the text “View all questions and answers” doesn’t show up.

Why I want this: it’ll be more consistent.

Example: [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/84913/ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica?tab=profile), under the top posts header.

Comment: Why? If it's a no-op, luring you to click it is just a distraction.

Comment: @tripleee it would show you all of those users questions and answers, it wouldn’t be a no-op. (I might be misunderstanding what you meant by no-op).

Comment: @EkadhSingh I think what tripleee meant is that it would be redundant because you can already see all posts. No-op: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)

Comment: If all of the posts are already displayed, I don't understand the point of adding the  links. I think it is a good thing that the text is dynamic, especially since I browse SE on my phone often. I appreciate it when the design doesn't take up space unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It seems that for the sake of consistency external site link icon should be added next to Network Profile link from dropdown "Profiles" menu on the right as it done for "View all" (Communities) link:

> [image: Profile page example]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Despite enough space on block the long tag name is displayed reduced. The following image from my [profile](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=profile) on ruSO Meta.

> [image: long badge name]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to join the discussion so late.
The responsive engine works fine overall, however, I noticed that on my SmartPhone, some icons were cut off.
I mean the "Site switcher" icon.

[image: Site switcher Icon is cut off]

This makes it difficult to click on this icon because it is too close to the edge of the smartphone screen.
I know that I can move the slider, but I think it would be better if the spacing between the icons would also get smaller.

Comment: You can scroll that header section with the cutoff icon. Try that and then lemme know if the icons are hard to tap.

Comment: As I said `I know that I can move the slider` and answering your question, trying to use them (scroll the slider) on 6,4'' Screen is difficult because it is thin slider, and the scrolling itself is more difficult than clicking on the cropped icon.. By the way, it looks as if there is a larger space between the first and second icons from the left, as if it is disproportionate to the remaining spaces between the other icons.

Comment: Your original post didn't have that text. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ You shouldn't have to use the slider itself, you can just fat thumb the whole content over.

Comment: Regardless, we've got some improvements around the top bar soon.

Comment: Aaaaa ... I can feel it now.
So it is a matter of developing a new habit. Thanks.

Comment: `Your original post didn't have that text.` This is because it is sometimes difficult to express complementary sentences in a foreign language. Moreover, the mind does not always collect all the relevant facts at once. This is what the discussion is for, to exchange comprehensive ideas ;)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The "Reputation gained since" tooltip in the summary section has too much empty space in the right margin.

[image: screenshot of reputation gained since]

Comment: There's space because otherwise the second "reputation" would be hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The *personal site* and *member since fields* have different text alignments. (I don't know why, maybe it's because the icons have different sizes?!)

[image: screenshot of member since and site fields]

It's also the case for the *location* and *member since* fields.

[image: screenshot of member since and location fields]

Comment: The first one is not a bug. That’s just normal kerning: the `j` always starts a little to the left. The second one is a bug: the location icon is 2px less wide than the others.

Comment: @SebastianSimon my initial thought was only reporting the location, but then I noticed the personal site and thought I might as well include it.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

There's a resolution range where the icons and text get misaligned and the buttons have different sizes. This happens for profiles with the default texts that are shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of badges section in profile page]

Answer (score 0):

Please add back the consecutive days so everyone can see it.

Every day, I make sure to manually visit the Stack Exchange sites.  This isn't easy, but somehow I managed to do it for almost 300 days.  Now only I can see it.

- **It isn't a design choice;** I can see it so it fits in perfectly.
- **It isn't a privacy concern;** there's nothing private about this.
- **It isn't to save space;** all it does is fill up what would be blank space

There is no considerable reason for this.  For no considerable reason, you've just erased all of this effort overnight.

Comment: just get rid of the badges too

Comment: Some people feel pressured by such metrics. There is no advantage for you to show the metric, but there is a disadvantage for these people if this metric is shown.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The advantage for me is that I don't feel as if I've been working for a job and the boss suddenly announced that I won't get a paycheck.

Comment: @Anonymous You get "paid" for your work by knowing that you are helping others - not by some statistic

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I mean the work of visiting the sites, not of contributing to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why bother visiting if you don't want to contribute?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do contribute, but I also visit the sites.

Comment: Re *"do it for almost 300 days"*: Why? Only ***you*** could see it. Was it to take a screenshot and [show it to others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-4444-days-4444-consecutive-in-their-profile)? Or hoping for *diamond* (not as in moderator) or *[platinum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum)* badges  to be introduced at some point, including one as the next level above [Fanatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188731#188731)? Or something else?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q It was because I thought SE wouldn't erase my progress for no reason.  Until they released the new profile pages, others could see it.  Then SE rewarded my dedication by making it so only I could see it and didn't even bother to give a reason on the post.

Answer (score -1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Right at the top of the profile page next to the user name. The moderator diamond seems to be slightly too high relative to the center of the blue moderator badge.

[image]

Using Windows 10 with Firefox 96.0

Comment: IMHO, that's seriously nitpicky (I wouldn't have noticed if you hadn't pointed it out).  I highly doubt they'll spend developer time on fixing something so small.

Comment: @Ollie that's your opinion and the devs didn't specify how large or small an issue should be for us to report it. If you want the site full of visual bugs, misalignment and inconsistencies speak for yourself but I'm willing to bet a lot of users (and probably the devs included) want it looking great!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just how these characters look in the font. Fwiw, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @Laurel you know what they say: *"Once you notice you can't stop looking at it."* So I was looking forward for someone with expertise to explain it one way or the other (that's usually been the case so far with the responsive redesign changes). I could point you to several dozen responsive design posts where users made wild claims that turned out to be wrong and took big issue with posts the devs validated soon afterwards. So unless it's an expert commenting I'll take comments from folks trying to invalidate other people's contributions with several grains of salt.

Comment: [Looks fine](//i.stack.imgur.com/FdDUZ.png) on Arch Linux, Firefox Nightly 98.0a1, Liberation Sans 12px. Wasn’t there one font that had a noticeably lower baseline which was mentioned a few times here?

Comment: Typing the text into the comment box under your feedback (answer) and taking a screenshot produces this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VEys.png - I added a couple of characters to show the extent of the text area (to show the limits of "top", "bottom", and underline's expected position). --- It doesn't seem *misaligned* it's just that the *crossbar* on the "e" is slightly lower than centerline, making the centerline of the diamond seem too high. --- The badge's diamond is a hair higher in your screenshot.

Comment: @Rob that's a pretty good catch and the best explanation thus far.

Comment: bad_coder: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367942/282094) (and another) identifies the CSS Element as "s-badge__moderator". That post is too old to offer feedback on. ---- From [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367899/282094): "As the labels are being laid out with a **new component** (that is **more complicated** than the Unicode ♦ ([IE: *not the same*])), and ... it has been difficult to get the positioning of the labels (in terms of margin between the display name, **vertical positioning**, padding, etc) to look "just right" in every instance across the site.".

Comment: @Rob when I get some time later I'll edit your 2 comments into my post. Really nice finds!!

Answer (score -4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

## Dark Mode

<sup>(Across the whole network)</sup>

Do I need to say more?

We already have this on Stack Overflow and this is perfect. I think it should work across the whole network.
I'm aware that some communities have background images that would need to be adapted, but it could be done progressively.

Also it would be nice if it used the browser's `prefer-color-scheme` attribute if the setting is not set or the user not logged in, because sometimes I view it not logged in (from another browser/device) and it is burning my eyes again.

Comment: _“but it could be done progressively”_ — It already is. All this is planned, and [pre-release builds of dark mode on more sites](/q/360198/289905#comment1202025_360198) already exist. The “System theme by default” has already been suggested here: [Make "system setting" the default for the Theme setting](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403576/4642212).

Comment: This is not related to the responsive profile changes, but I'm going to comment anyways ;). Dark mode across the whole network is something we're actively working towards, but there's still a lot of work to be done. We've been rolling out a lot of behind-the-scenes changes to network theming that users ([usually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641/why-did-all-sites-turn-orange)) don't notice to get us closer to our ideal theming state. I don't have any news or a concrete timeline at the moment, so thank you for your continued patience on the matter.