# Username on mobile-sized responsive profile page is messy in some cases

Tags: bug, profile-page, responsive-design

The username is kinda messy in some profiles as the spacing is not appropriate. Look at these screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of Vanny's profile]

[image: Screenshot of The Amplitwist's profile]

- Browser: Firefox 94.1.2 (Build #2015844587)
- OS: Android 11

Please fix this issue.

Comment: Also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371319/1017231)

Comment: Also relevant: [this report](/a/371506/289905).