# Make profile page "Answers" and "Questions" clickable links

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, hyperlinks

When you visit the [new profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile), you see the Answers and Questions columns below:

---

[image: Answers | Questions]

---

Neither the `Answers` or `Questions` headers are hyperlinks.

You must click below on `"View all 123 answers"` or `"View all 123 questions"` to get to the All page.

Every time I want to go to my Answers or Questions, I first misclick on the non-link header text expecting it to be a link. This is very annoying.

Please link the header text to the same page as the smaller text below.

You could (potentially) even remove the small "view all" text after making the main header clickable.