# Moderator flair and "Meta user" link overlap

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-interface, mobile-chrome

Moderator flair and "Meta user" link overlap sometimes, eg from https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez on Chrome for Android on a Google Pixel 6:

[image]

Comment: This is the same in essence as [what I reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371319/323179) (though I don't have an example of mods or staff with this bug).

Comment: And the alignment of the mod flair is also off

Comment: For me, chrome on android, huawei P20 pro, the name wraps below the image, so no conflict.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371506