# "network profile" and "unregistered" overlap on some profile

Tags: bug, status-review, user-interface, unregistered-users, mobile-chrome

"network profile" and "unregistered" overlap on some profile.

Example from https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/83718/christine-adams:

[image]

Tested on Chrome on Android (Pixel 6).

Comment: So we meet again. I'll just drop this [comment link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377693/moderator-flair-and-meta-user-link-overlap#comment1260501_377693) here :p

Comment: Also related: [User name overlaps Network Profile button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387867/986753) (and see the comments there as well)

Comment: @Laurel thanks, my Alzheimer's strikes again

Comment: I checked in Android 13 Chrome and Firefox and couldn't reproduce this issue.

Comment: @RandomPerson thanks, maybe you have a different screen size? I have android 12 but I doubt that the android version makes any difference

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt My screen size is 6.1 inches.

Comment: Link not working now. Page not found :(

Comment: @RandomPerson I guess they got banned. Mine is 6.4 in