# Long usernames overlap with the Profiles/Network profile button on mobile

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-chrome

In the full site on mobile, long usernames overlap with the Profiles or the Network Profile button.

Examples:

- > [image]
- > [image]

This happens when the user only has "Member for { } day(s)/month(s)/year(s)" and "Last seen *this* week" under their username<sup>1</sup>. This does *not* happen when a user has "Last seen *more than a* week/month/year ago", "Member for {1-12} year(s), { } day(s)/month(s)" or any other information below their username.

<sup>1</sup> In this case, the position of the username is shifted next to the profile picture, so a long username would then overlap with the Profiles/Network profile button..

Examples of this issue *not* happening:

- > [image]
- > [image]

I'm using Chrome for Android.

Comment: This also happens for "unregistered" users. See my [answer on the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371319/323179) which reports both issues.

Comment: Looks like the wrapping is based on the meta-info "Member for [...]", not considering the length of the username.

Comment: Also posted on Meta Anime.SE: [Username with special characters gets displaced in profile dashboard. Bug?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4532/2516) (title a bit misleading before knowing the cause)