# Moderator sign is overlapping with network profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, responsive-design

[image]

As you can see, the moderator and network profile overlap each other.

I am on Chrome (version 103.0.5060.71) for Android, resolution 2220×1080 on mobile.

Comment: Also related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378753/long-usernames-overlap-with-the-profiles-network-profile-button-on-mobile. Probably the same issue.

Comment: Similar, earlier: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371319/282094

Comment: That is different, network profile is different than meta user, but maybe they point towards the same problem