# User name overlaps Network Profile button

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, responsive-design

In this [user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1285139/jovan-radenkovic) the user name overlaps "Network profile" button on narrow screen:

> [image]

Yet [another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1339979/0-insomniac-0):

> [image]

And even for [staff member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1251582/collin-choy):

> [image]

Comment: Similar to this report (which is marked [status-completed]): [Letters in profile name overlap with the edit profile button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371112).

Comment: Another similar report: ["Unregistered" overlaps the Network Profile button on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371319).

Comment: The overlap of the "Staff" and "Moderator" labels has already been reported here: ["Network profile" overlaps with page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371506).